# PHP form doesn't always seem to write to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On a form I've built, the form is validated with Javascript spry validation and then after that it is sent to a php form which pulls in the post fields with the POST method.

There is then a sql query as below to submit the data to the database.

```
$title = $_POST["title"];
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$address1 = $_POST["address1"];
$address2 = $_POST["address2"];
$town = $_POST["town"];
$county = $_POST["county"];
$country = $_POST["countries"];
$telephone_home = $_POST["telephone-home"];
$telephone_mobile = $_POST["telephone-mobile"];
$comments = $_POST["comments"];
$letter = $_POST["q1-letter"];
$updates = $_POST["q1-updates"];
$paye = $_POST["PAYE"];

//establish connection
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","#######","###########","############"); 
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } 


mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO wp_donations (prefix, first_name, second_name, amount, address1, address2, citytown, county, country, email, comments, letter, updates, paye)
    VALUES ('$title','$first_name','$surname','$amount2','$address1','$address2','$town','$county','$country','$email','$comments','$letter','$updates','$paye')");
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Now most of the time this appears to be working perfectly fine, and any tests I've done work as well. However my client is reporting that there is entries of the form which aren't showing up in the database. This form is used to process a payment, and the client cross checks the payments with the information in the database and the payment processors logs.

I can't for the life of me figure out how some of them might not be showing up in the database, as there is no way to process the payment without going via this php page (it also contains the payment processing components)

Could there be something I'm missing here that could allow a payment to be processed, but not show up in the database?

Your help is always much appreciated

Comment: It could be that data is breaking your SQL, your not using `mysql_escape_string()`, switch to mysqli or PDO 'prepare'. I.E. what if surname is O'Neil

Comment: He is using mysqli, its just he is not doing it right/safely

Comment: Please tell me you know about SQL Injection Attacks...

Comment: imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png"

Comment: do you mean http://xkcd.com/327/ - edit: sorry the `"` made it 404 for me d'oh!

Comment: you should write the errors to a log to figure out what is going on insetad of just outputting it

Comment: @Waygood my link is the full size picture

Comment: Also just using javascript for validation is not a good idea, validate client and server side

Comment: Forgive me guys but I'm new enough to these SQL queries. But I think Waygood has spotted something, the entries that aren't showing up are ones like "O'Neill" so that's obviously the issue then! What is it then  that I need to do to fix this, along with preventing the SQL injection attacks?

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Thanks deceze looks like a good read!

Comment: the way you have it, if any of the form elements have a single quote in them it will terminate the field. You need to use prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

You are just taking post variables as you get them, which is a bad idea. But aside the potential for sql injection, let's take a look at a basic example which I believe is what's happening in your case:

```
$x = $_POST['x'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`address`) VALUES ('$x')";
```

Now let's suppose `$x` is `1234 Captain's Creek rd`

Your query will now look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`address`) VALUES ('Captain's Creek rd')";
```

Do you see the problem there? That ' in the string terminates that field and the lingering string trailing the quoted value is a syntax error, which will cause your query to fail.

If you [bind the parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), you can have mysqli escape the input values:

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`address`) VALUES (?)");
$sql->bind_param("s", $x);
$sql->execute();
```

If you have questions feel free to ask and I may update.

Comment: This is a great answer to the question, but read [This Link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to gain a better understanding of how `bind_param` works if you have a more complicated query.

Comment: which is linked in the answer. you should actually look over a complete tutorial on mysqli or familiarize yourself with other people's suggestions of safeguarding against injections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate variables

Like this...

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO wp_donations (prefix, first_name, second_name, amount, address1, address2, citytown, county, country, email, comments, letter, updates, paye)
                                      VALUES ('".$title."','".$first_name."','".$surname."','".$amount2."','".$address1."','".$address2."','".$town."','".$county."','".$country."','".$email."','".$comments."','".$letter".','".$updates."','".$paye."')");
```

Comment: this is not the reason for the error. You can access variables like he is doing if you are using double quoted strings